Why $M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ is a clean ring
An element $a$ of a ring $R$ is said to be clean element if it can be written as the sum of unit and idempotent. If every element of $R$ is clean then we say that $R$ is clean ring. I am trying to prove $M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ i.e ring of $n\times n$ matrices over rationals is a clean ring. Suppose $n=2$, then we have to write arbitrary matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a&b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ as a sum of idempotent and unit, for this I tried $\begin{bmatrix} a&b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$=$\begin{bmatrix} a&b \\ c & 0 \end{bmatrix}$+$\begin{bmatrix}0 &0 \\ 0 & d \end{bmatrix}$. Clearly, $\begin{bmatrix} a&b \\ c & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is unit when $b$ and $c$ are nonzero. But $\begin{bmatrix}0 &0 \\ 0 & d \end{bmatrix}$ is only idempotent when $d$ is idempotent. How to proceed further?

Wikipedia mentions that matrix rings over clean rings are clean with the reference

Hana, Juncheol; Nicholson, W. K. (2001). "Extensions of Clean Rings". Communications in Algebra. 29 (6): 2589–2595. doi:10.1081/AGB-100002409.


Here is a direct proof that $M_2(K)$ is clean when $K$ is a field.
Assume $a \in M_2(K)$ is not clean. Then for every idempotent element $e \in M_2(K)$ we have $\det(a-e)=0$. For the idempotent elements $e = 0,1,E_{1,1},E_{2,2}$ we get the equations
$\begin{align}
(1) \quad 0 &= a_{11} a_{22} - a_{21} a_{12} \\
(2) \quad 0 &= (a_{11} - 1) (a_{22} - 1) - a_{21} a_{12} \\
(3) \quad 0 &= (a_{11} - 1) a_{22} - a_{21} a_{12} \\
(4) \quad 0 &= a_{11} (a_{22} - 1) - a_{21} a_{12}
\end{align}$
From (1) and (4) we get $a_{11} = 0$. From (1) and (3) we get $a_{22} = 0$. Then (1) simplifies to $0 = a_{21} a_{12}$, and (2) simplifies to $0 = 1 - a_{21} a_{12}$, a contradiction.

I wonder if we can prove in a coordinate-free way that it is not possible that $f : V \to V$ is a linear map such that $\ker(f - p) \neq 0$ for all projections $p : V \to V$.

Nice solution! If, in your comment, you meant $\ker(f-p) = 0$, then you can decompose $V$ in a sum of (cyclic $f$-stable) subspaces where $f$ is a unit (done!) or nilpotent, then you can consider $f=\mathrm{id}+(-\mathrm{id}+f)$.

No, I meant $\ker(f - p) \neq 0$. The statement I wrote is equivalent to $f = p + u$ for some idempotent $p$ and some unit $u$.

If you have found another proof that $\mathrm{End}(V)$ is clean, please post a separate answer (brings extra visibility).

@MartinBrandenburg One of the classical results is that endomorphism rings of continuous modules are clean.  I'm not familiar with the proof, but it may be worth looking at.  When I initially saw the post I was thinking it was probably possible to do this along the lines of "unit-regular implies clean" since it gives matrix rings like these the property that every element is a product of a unit and an idempotent.

Here is a coordinate-free proof that $\operatorname{End}(V)$ is clean for any finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over a field (so in particular $M_n(\Bbb Q)$ for any $n$). Let $T\in \operatorname{End}(V)$. Let $m$ be $T$'s minimal polynomial and factor $m=(x-1)^kg$ with $g(1)\ne0$ and $k\geq0$. Then we have a decomposition (as a $k[T]$-module) $V=V_1\oplus W$ with $V_1=\ker((T-1)^k)$ and $W=\ker g(T)$. Let $P$ the projection onto $W$ with kernel $V_1$ corresponding to this decomposition. Then $T-P$ is invertible. Indeed, $T=T\rvert_{V_1}\oplus T\rvert_W$ and $P=0\rvert_{V_1}\oplus I_W$, so $T-P = (T\rvert_{V_1})\oplus (T\rvert_{W}-I_W)$ and both $T\rvert_{V_1}$ and $T\rvert_{W}-I_W$ are invertible (on $V_1,W$ respectively).
So $T=(T-P) + P $ is the sum of a unit and an idempotent.
